# Wordpress Issue creating a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm beginner wp developing him learning how to create my first shortcode on WordPress so a user that add shortcode `[contact_form]` to Page or Post will see it on any page of their theme.

Here Message
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_shortcode' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /Users/brandonpowell/sites/valet/wordpress-development/web/app/themes/sage-8.5.0/lib/shortcode.php on line 16`

```
<?php

class Settings {
      // Conact Form shortcode
      public function allb_contact_form( $atts, $content = null  ) {
        //[contact_form]
        //get the attribute_escape
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(),
            $atts,
            'contact_form'
          );
          //return HTML
          include 'lib/inc/thmeplates/contact-form.php';

    add_shortcode( 'contact_form', 'allb_contact_form' ); // Line 16
  }
new Settings();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just your formatting

```
class Settings {
      // Conact Form shortcode

    public function allb_contact_form( $atts, $content = null  ) {
          //[contact_form]
          //get the attribute_escape
          $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(),
            $atts,
            'contact_form'
          );
          //return HTML
          include 'lib/inc/thmeplates/contact-form.php';

        add_shortcode( 'contact_form', 'allb_contact_form' ); // Line 16
    }

}// this was missing
```

Comment: Thank you don't know why miss that. I have one more question I have created a form inside of contact-form.php but not included on WordPress site.  Just show the [contact_form].

Comment: you will need to ask a new question showing your code. Watch for hooks on pre get the content